# Triple quotation in python

Tags: python, syntax

So I understand that if I do the following

```
print """ Anything I 
          type in here 
          works. Multiple LINES woohoo!"""
```

But what if following is my python script

```
""" This is my python Script. Just this much """
```

What does the above thing do? Is it taken as comment? Why is it not a syntax error?

Similarly, if I do

```
"This is my Python Script. Just this. Even with single quotes."
```

How are the above two scripts interpreted?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The triple quotes `'''` or `"""` are just different ways of representing strings. The advantage of triple quotes is that it can span multiple lines and sometimes serve as [**docstrings**](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

The reason:

`"hadfasdfas"`

doesn't raise any error is because python simply creates the string and then doesn't assign it to anything. For the python interpreter, it is perfectly fine if you have a pointless statement in your code as long as there are no syntax or semantics errors

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

The string is just evaluated, and the interpreter noticing it wasn't assigned to anything, throws it away.

But in some special places, this string is actually assigned to the `__doc__` property of the item:

```
def func(arg):
  """
  Does stuff. This string will be evaluated and assigned to func.__doc__.
  """
  pass

class Test:
  """
  Same for Test.__doc__
  """
  pass
```

At the top of `module.py`:

```
"""
module does stuff. this will be assigned to module.__doc__
"""
def func():
...
```

Comment: Yeah, I missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @sshashank124 answer I have to add that triple quoted strings are also used in testing https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html

So consider this code snippet:

```
def some_function(x, y):
"""This function should simply return sum of arguments.
It should throw an error if you pass string as argument

>>> some_function(5, 4)
9
>>> some_function(-5, 4)
-1
>>> some_function("abc", 4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
ValueError: arguments must numbers
"""
if type(x, str) or type(y, str):
    raise ValueError("arguments must numbers")
else:
    return x + y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

If you import this tiny module, you'll get the `some_function` function.
But if you invoke this script directly from shell, tests given in the triple quoted string will be evaluated and the report will be printed to the output.

So triple quoted strings can be treated as values of type string, as comment, as docstrings and as containers for unittests.

Comment: I don not get it, so what exactly happens when I run this script. For one, I am not sure what will be the value for x and y?  Can you please elaborate. Thanks

Comment: If you save it as a file with extension `.py` like `some_module.py` it becomes a module. If you import it then `__name__ == "__main__"` is `False` so no magic happens. But if you invoke it from shell i.e. `python some_module.py` the last two lines gets executed. In this case `doctest.testmod()` will scan docstring for Python unittests. So it finds `>>>` which means `execute`. In my snippet first unittest calls `some_function(5, 4)`. The expected result of this call is placed in next line. Sometimes exception is expected like in the third unittest. Test succeeds if the result is as expected.