# What exactly the three inverted commas (''') stands for in Python

Tags: python

In this question, I would like to know whether there is a convention for the ''' triple inverted commas in Python.

In one, online course I came across the idea that, don't use triple inverted commas because it uses to denote documentation of the program.

In another, online course I came across the idea that, use it when necessary. Then you can use single or double inverted commas as you like.

```
print('''This is exactly what he said, "I'm your lover."''')
```

What are your thoughts on this? Is there any specific convention?

Thank you very much in advance for the help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361171/triple-quotation-in-python

Answer (score 3):

Triple quotes are usually used for multi-line comments (or documentation as you mentioned!) by convention.

The interpreter will not ignore them as comments though.

> Triple quotes, according to official Python documentation are docstrings, or multi-line docstrings and are not considered comments. Anything inside triple quotes is read by the interpreter. When the interpreter encounters the hash symbol, it ignores everything after that. That is what a comment is defined to be.

[Read more!](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/triple-quotes-in-python/)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever this `""" """` or this `''' '''` in Python you use it for multiline strings
For example:

```py
a = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."""
```

As you can see if I want to assign a long line of text. Then I'll use them.