# pyscopg2 select causing undefinedcolumn error for this below program

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

I am new to postgresql and python. Could you please help me to fix this issue. I am getting undefined column error while fetching with where caluse. PostgreSQL 14 and python 3.8 version has been used.

```
import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect(database="dbname",user="postgres",password="pwd",host="localhost",port= '5432')
cursor_obj = con.cursor()
#print(s3.x)
x = 'select "*" FROM PUBLIC."tab1" '
y = 'where "SSN"="123-45-6789" '
#z = '"123-45-6789"'
a = x + y
cursor_obj.execute(a)    

#cursor_obj.execute('SELECT "SSN" FROM PUBLIC."tab1" where "SSN" = "123-45-6789 "')    
result = cursor_obj.fetchall()
print("Result set:","\n",result)
con.commit()
con.close()
ere
```

Error:
UndefinedColumn: column "123-45-6789" does not exist
LINE 1: ...NFD-SSN" FROM PUBLIC."tab1" where "SSN"="123-45-67...

I tried changing the apostrophes but still didn't work

Comment: The problem is that "123-45-6789" is being recognised as the name of the column itself, rather than an entry in a column.

Comment: Which apostrophes did you change, what did you change them to, and what happened?  ("didn't work" is not a description, it is an excuse provided in lieu of a description)

Comment: 1) Read up on Python [Triple quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361171/triple-quotation-in-python). 2) In Postgres "<some_string>" means you are writing an identifier, a table or column name. 3) Is `SSN` actually all upper case in the table definition? 4) Read up on [Passing parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

Comment: Thanks all. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70621488/python-find-a-string-with-single-quote-symbol-in-postgresql-table post helped mt to fix the issue.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 95 and 9.4 are [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: I hope that does not mean you used `f` string formatting to build your query.